# Display event attenders : Eventbrite / Eventful implementation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, eventbrite

I'm am creating a event listing website like **eventbrite.com**. There are organizers who can create events and users who can register for events.

Users need to login to the system via Facebook. In this case I get to store their facebook_id.

My question is, how can I get a particular user's friend list (friends who are attending the event) and display below the event?

Actually I have an idea for this:

**Solution I**
When a logged in user attending an event, I can save his facebook_id with the event id.

**Event attenders table**
facebook_id  |  ----   Event _id
42343453424  |  ----   08
34534534544  |  ----   08
23424243224  |  ----   10

When another user logs in, I can get his friends facebook_ids and try to match with the 
Event attenders table.

Example:
user_friend_list = [ 42343453424 , 23424243224 , 4345345345 , 245345433 ,...etc ]

I have to get the 1st user form the user_friend_list array (42343453424) and search in the **Event attenders table**, and the second user (23424243224) , and the third user so on.

This method needs to run lots of loops and queries. This will cause a huge delay in the site.

Can anyone please suggest me a better solution of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

-PS

1. In eventbrite.com and eventful.com and there's a Facebook app that do this work. how to create such a Facebook book app to do this work.
2. If I have multiple events on my homepage and I want to display the attenders list below each and every event once a user logs in. Is this possible to do smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running all those individual database hits, why don't you bring back all attendees for an event in 1 query and store them in an array. Then get all a users friends and store them in another array. Finally loop through the list of attendees and use the in_array method to check if the current attendee is in the friend array. Then you can store these in a third array that is all the matching friends

e.g

```
 $matching = array();
 $attending = array(); // This is populated from your database
 $friends = array(); // This would be populated from their facebook friendlist

 $foreach($attending as $attendee){
       if(in_array($attendee, $friends)){
            // This attendee is present in their friends list so add them to matching
            $matching[] = $attendee;
       }
 }

 //Loop through matching to show all the friends who are attending.
```